# jqxInput: Unable to scroll after apply CSS

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

Using jqxInput, we decide to expand the list of selection by not limiting to 8 (by default).

```
$("#input").jqxInput({
    items:100
});
```

But we got a long list of inputs but without scrolling, refer to http://jsfiddle.net/Zz5GN/28/

Tweak *jqx-menu-vertical-energyblue { height: 150px !important; overflow-y: scroll; ]* but unfortunately, the scroll is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with jqxInput I've come to to the conclusion that the items will not be displayed if you give the vertical menu your own height. And if possible always try to avoid using !important, it's you could say, important to practice.

Comment: The jqxInput on screen render will replace the height, that's why I include the !important.

Answer (score 0):

Official answer from jqWidget, "No, this is not supported."
http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/jqxinput-autocomplete-scrollbar-for-the-panel/

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this solution? (Tested with the v9.0.0 (2020-Jan))

```
/**
 * Extend the jqxInput component.
 * 
 * Extend the jqxInput component to override the click to fix a bug when user click on scrollbar.
 */
(function(a) {
    var originalClick = a.jqx._jqxInput.prototype.click;

    a.extend(a.jqx._jqxInput.prototype, {
        click: function(b) {
            var hasClass = $(b.target).hasClass("jqx-popup");
            if (!hasClass) {
                return originalClick.call(this, b);
            }
        }
    });
})(jqxBaseFramework);
```